# need to sort a table so the whole table is sorted not just one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

how to I sort a table so the whole table is sorted.  Imagine I have 10x10 table with numbers 1-100 that are placed randomly in the table. I want the table sorted so the first column has 1-10 then the next column would start with 11 next column would start with 21  etc..
Thanks for any help.
Dave

Comment: Select the table and sort it. Sort first by column A ascending, then column B ascending, then column C ascending, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a **Table** from the data and named it `Table1`

To  create the sorted list, enter the formula below into some cell, and fill right for the appropriate number of columns (*or, since there is the `IFERROR` function, until you see blanks*)

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(Table1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1),,(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*ROWS(Table1)+1)),"")
```

**Data**
[image]

**Sorted**
[image]

- If you don't want to use a table, you can replace the name with a range reference.
- If your values are not numeric, `Power Query` would be a better solution.
- If you don't have the `SEQUENCE` function, you can use:

```
    =IFERROR(SMALL(Table1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*ROWS(Table1)+1):INDEX($A:$A,(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*ROWS(Table1)+ROWS(Table1)))),"")
```

Comment: Thanks Ron, I dont have the sequence function so the second formula worked.  not sure if you can ask this or if I need to ask a 'new' question.  how would i rework your formula to skip every other column?  Thank you for the help. - Dave

Comment: @DavidLake It should be a new question. But the principal would be that for each **fill right** you would increment the `column_number` argument by 2 instead of 1

Comment: simply enough. thank you for the help

Comment: @DavidLake Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require for your original question, I'd appreciate it if you would mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).